Connect to Flipper Zero via Serial Port and install a file
How can I connect to a Flipper Zero using JS and send a file to /int/ and/or reboot the Flipper?
Any help is Appreciated!
This is the code I currently have. It just connects to the Flipper:
const connect = async () => {
  try {
    flipper = await navigator.serial.requestPort({ filters: [{ usbVendorId: 0x0483 }] });
    await flipper.open({ baudRate: 9600 });
    writer = flipper.writable.getWriter();
    connected = true;
    // console.log("flipper connected!");
  } catch (error) {
    // console.error('Error opening the serial port:', error);
  }
};

This works fine but i can not quite figure out how to send any commands or files
